# ReactNative WebView - It only displays a text that reads "Loading ..."

Tags: android, webview, react-native

I am opening in my WebView the following URL:

```
https://auth.mercadopago.com.ve/authorization?client_id=6012820321480442&response_type=code&platform_id=mp&redirect_uri=https://localhost/mercadoPagoConnect?userId=cljvLoUJNoOHfe636ofMHduXu2o2
```

The same opens correctly but when the fields of the form are filled and the form is sent my WebView leaves the blank screen showing the message "Loading ..." and does not pass from there, and in the log I do not see any error, Is there any way to view the WebView log?.

This is my code:

```
            <View style={{
                flex: 1
            }}>
                <WebView onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)} onMessage={(event) => console.log('onMessage:', event.nativeEvent.data)} onError={(e) => {
                    console.log(e);
                }} source={{
                    uri: this.state.url
                }} automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false} scalesPageToFit={true} javaScriptEnabled={false} domStorageEnabled={false} startInLoadingState={true} style={{
                    flex: 1
                }}/>
            </View>
```

Version are:

```
"react": "15.4.2",
"react-native": "0.42.0",
```

After logging in you should enter the following screen:

[image: Api authorization screen]

Thank you

Comment: It looks good to me - can you reproduce it at https://snack.expo.io/S1QX92zRx ?

Comment: It proves in the url that you passed me and has the same behavior, you can prove using this user data: "user": "TETE5691798", "password": "qatest6094"

When you hit the Enter button it stays there saying "Loading ..."

Comment: It looks good to me! Here is a link: https://snack.expo.io/r1J11TG0e I've added an alert to see what url it is trying to redirect to after logging in successfully. Here is a [screenshot](https://s11.postimg.org/mo0flq043/Screen_Shot_2017-04-18_at_01.17.01.png).

Comment: Of course, but as you observe it stays stuck there, and does not show the URL page that shows you in the alert, it is supposed to show you the next screen, upload a picture to the question. https://snack.expo.io/BkEaWaMRl

Comment: Yes that it still ok because in my screenshot, if you notice the url it has a an error about the `redirect_url`. In the url you provided, there is a `redirect_uri` (points to `localhost`) which does not exist for me. Maybe you are running a backend locally or something? I think the `WebView` behaves correctly. It is your server settings you need to adjust.

Comment: Can you try the link of expo.io in my last comment i update the URL if you use this URL in your desktop browser you can see its work fine.