# WebView not loading page, after form submit

Tags: android, webview, react-native

Looking to solve a problem that I have with React Native with the component of WebView [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43460208/reactnative-webview-it-only-displays-a-text-that-reads-loading), I did a direct test in android obtaining the same error when trying to load a specific page.

The first page contains a form, but after entering the user data and submitting, it does not show the next page, it only shows a message of "Loading ..."

This is my android code:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView .getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView .getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://auth.mercadopago.com.ve/authorization?client_id=6012820321480442&response_type=code&platform_id=mp&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fus-central1-quicpyapp.cloudfunctions.net%2FmercadoPagoConnect%3FuserId%3DcljvLoUJNoOHfe636ofMHduXu2o2");

}
```

}

I have also been able to observe that the page works correctly if I comment the following line:

```
//webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

The test user data are as follows:"user": "TETE5691798", "password": "qatest6094"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you need to display login screen on webview?

Comment: I need to display that login screen, to obtain authorization of a third party API, they after the user is logged shows another screen where the user has to confirm the authorization, but that next screen is never shown, at least I comment the line of code that i specify in my question.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the `onReceivedHttpAuthRequest()`, it'll authenticate your website automatically. Try this code below:

```
      mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
                mWebView.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword(host, realm, YOUR_USER_NAME, YOUR_PASSWORD);
                handler.proceed(YOUR_USER_NAME, YOUR_PASSWORD);
            }

      }
```

Comment: The problem is not to login, the problem is that it never shows the next page after the login, it stays in an infinite loop trying to load the next page and only shows the word "Loading ..."

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
var currentUrl = "google.com" 
var partOfUrl = currentUrl.substring(0, currentUrl.length-2)

webView.setWebViewClient(object: WebViewClient() {

 override fun onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
 //call loadUrl() method  here 
 // also check if url contains partOfUrl, if not load it differently.
 if(url.contains(partOfUrl, true)) {
     //it should work if you reach inside this if scope.
 } else if(!(currentUrl.startWith("w", true))) {
     webView.loadurl("www.$currentUrl")

 } else if(!(currentUrl.startWith("h", true))) {
     webView.loadurl("https://$currentUrl")

 } else { 
  //...
 }


 }

 override fun onReceivedSslError(view: WebView?, handler: SslErrorHandler?, error: SslError?) {
// you can call again loadUrl from here too if there is any error.
}
//You should also override other override method for error such as onReceiveError to see how all these methods are called one after another and how they behave while debugging with break point. 
}
```